# Trying to center a nested column in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb foundation and i'm trying to center a nested column but for a reason i cannot fathom, it is not centering it. Could anyone shed some light on this please?!

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12 columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="4 centered columns">
                    <h1>My Content</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ha! Answered my own question here, turns out i was writing the number instead of the word for the amount of columns. What a goon!

Answer (score 6):

May be `4` was incorrect and you should try `four` and the same for twelve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Foundation 3, try

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="12 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="4 centered columns">
          <h1>My Content</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found the closing `<div>` tags were unbalanced.

If you are using Foundation 4, use

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 large-centered columns">
          <h1>My Content</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```